# How do I prove the general formulation of LRV to verify that LRV for AR(1) is in fact (σ²)/(1-α)²

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, econometrics, autoregressive

[image]

I understand the equations separately but don’t know how they are connected!  Please give me an explanation / hint

Given the AR(1) structure, the long run variance (LRV) of Xt is known to be (σ²)/(1-α)², use general formulation of the LRV of any stationary and ergodic process defined in the photo, to verify from **first principles** that the LRV for the AR (1) is in fact (σ²)/(1-α)².

Please see attached image.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: I understand the equations separately but don’t know how they are connected. And I’m new to here , I don’t know how to write the expressions on the computer therefore I uploaded a photo.

Comment: You can use $`LaTeX$  here, just pt formulas inbetween dolar signs, as in $x_i^2$  written as `$x_i^2$`.  See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated